# Alarm Manager not Triggering Properly

Tags: android

If the following line of code is used, the Alarm is triggered immediately by `AlarmManager`, which is normal since Android documentation states that if an Alarm is set in the past it will be triggered immediately.

```
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60*60*24*1000, alarmIntent);
```

Meanwhile, by setting it to trigger 1 minute later, using the code here after `adding +60*1000 to System.currentTimeMillis()`, the Alarm will not be triggered 1 minute later, as it should (actually the Alarm will never be triggered, even after waiting for 10 additional minutes - perhaps it will the day after, when repeating, but I have not tested this yet).

```
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+60*1000, 60*60*24*1000, alarmIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your API level.

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS
>   will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There
>   are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and
>   setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose
>   targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the
>   previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when
>   requested.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Thank you Kuffs. I am aware of this, meanwhile (I should have specified this in my post), the Alarm never triggers, even after waiting for 10 additional minutes. J

Comment: I will try your suggestion as soon as I have access to my environment, but I am not sure why the brackets would make a difference. Thank you. J

Comment: I see... But that wouldn't be respecting basic arithmetic concepts. I will try as soon as I can and let you know the results. Thank you for your time. J

Comment: Maybe waiting 10 minutes just isn't enough. It doesn't say in the documentation how long the wakeup window will be. It could be 30 or even 60 minutes depending on other factors on the device.